# Using Microsoft Virtual WiFi to connect to 2nd network

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, ad-hoc-network, virtual-wifi

I have read up a bit on the Microsoft Virtual WiFi feature in Windows 7, and am confused as to its capabilities. Does this allow me to connect to two networks using a single physical wireless adapter? Or does it only allow me to turn my computer into a wireless access point? My end goal is to be able to get onto one WiFi network to connect to the internet and another to connect to a wireless printer so I can print from it.